# Change of AppDelegate class on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appdelegate

I have a cocoa project on OSX. For that, I had to change the class of the Appdelegate.
I did this in two steps: First I implemented the new appdelegate class (I didn't implement the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol yet) and checked if it worked and compiled. In the new class I already implemented the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. Everything was still fine!

After that I changed the protocol implementation. I removed the prorocol from the old Appdelegate and inserted it in the new one. Even after this step everything seemed to be fine! The application compiled and worked as it should. But as I was somewhat sceptical, I inserted log statements in the new and the old class.

After inserting this, I had to see, that the application still used the old appdelegate! 
Obviously, there is something where the name of the old appdelegate is still known! But where is that? Or do I have to do something else to reach my goal? Does anyone know what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that have to happen: 1) an instance of your new class has to be instantiated. 2) That instance needs to be assigned to the `delegate` property of the application object (instance of `NSApplication` or a subclass).

In a typical Mac app, both of those things are done in the MainMenu NIB. That NIB contains a freeze-dried instance of the appropriate class. If you were to build the NIB from scratch, you would drag an "Object" (blue cube) from the Object library to the NIB document. By default, that would represent an instance of `NSObject`. You would then select it and bring up the Identity inspector where you would change its class to your new app delegate class. Since you're not building the NIB from scratch, there's already an Object in the NIB. You can select it and change its class.

The other step, assigning it to the `delegate` property of the application object, is done by connecting the `delegate` outlet of the placeholder for the application object in the NIB to the object. Again, since you're not building the NIB from scratch, that's already done.

So, in summary, you just need to change the class of the app delegate object in the MainMenu NIB.

---

Update: Here's a screen shot of what you have to change:

[image]

Comment: Your answer reminded me, that I forgot to mention, that I also renamed the "object" in IB. What's missing, is assigning the delegate property...  Unfortunately, there is no delegate property at the new class. So what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, just saw, that File's owner has a delegate property (an outlet) assigned to the new object
btw, File's owner is NSApplication

Comment: Renaming the object is not the same as changing its class.

Comment: Well, that's understood! The name was changed by refactoring the class. Nonetheless it does not have a delegate property to connect.

Comment: *Your* class doesn't need a delegate property. The ``delegate`` property belongs to the *File's Owner* which is the ``NSApplication`` instance, and you probably aren't changing this. You need to do two things. Firstly highlight the *File's Owner* cube, then in the *Connections Inspector* drag from the *delegate* outlet to the cube that represents your new class. Adjust your new class's ``.h`` file to signal that it implements the ``NSApplicationDelegate`` protocol, then implement the protocol.